# VBA to loop through all worksheets and clear cell contents

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I have the code below and I keep getting runtime error 438, can someone help me debug? Thanks!

```
Sub my sub ()

Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(link to file)

Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In wb
    ws.Cells.ClearContents
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: `For Each ws In wb.Worksheets`.

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

Dim ws As Worksheet
'Loop all sheet in the workbook
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    'Clear the used range of the sheet
    ws.UsedRange.Clear 'or .ClearContents
Next ws

End Sub
```